# Disable remote mail in exim

Tags: email, unix, remote, smtp

i am a web developer and have exim4 installed on my dev box, recently i needed to send a scripted email to a few project managers and so got exim heavy and all that setup which went well. Now i'm back to developing system emails locally (password reset etc) i'd like to switch exim to deny all remote email addresses as i don't want any chance of email leaving my development environment, reconfiguring exim seems like the wrong way to go about it.

Is there a config setting for this or a hack to make all remote mail fail? googling has left me puzzled.

Comment: I see you rollbacked my edit regarding the [tag:disable] tag cleanup. Please go [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8165/disable-virtual-menus) for information on this cleanup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable all "routers" that deal with outgoing mail – `domain_literal`, `dnslookup` by default, but there might be others. Look at the `transport` field of every router.

(Note: I cannot answer any questions about the multi-file macro-generated configuration mess such as the one found in Debian. I'm sticking with a small `exim.conf` myself.)

Comment: do you know how i can tell which router is being used, setting domain_literal, domain_literal_relay and dnslookup to LOCAL_DELIVERY has no effect, must be using another if LOCAL_DELIVERY value is right?

Comment: @Question: `sudo exim -bt` (with optional `-d`) and enter a local user name (such as "root"), it will tell you the router chosen and transport used. (Regarding "LOCAL_DELIVERY value", I will repeat that I cannot answer any questions about configs generated from macro templates. I don't understand that stuff myself.)

Comment: brilliant sudo exim -v -d -bt remote@example.com gave me more than enough info cheers, spoiling the transport (remote_smtp_junk) in dnslookup did the trick